# Action Android action Bar with fragments loads views but i want to load activities which in themselves loads views(as in tabhost)

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I am currently stuck at one point.If i am using actionbar(NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS) with fragments.I want the fragment to be a activity which will handle all the view loading and everything.currently fragmant class will extend Fragment..Right?but i want somethhing like extending activity then calling oncreate.

Please help.

```
enter code here

final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();//(TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);//  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, X.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("jbn jb n").setIndicator("gjngjmb ",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.home))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyCoursesActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("my_course").setIndicator("My Courses",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.courses))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DashboardActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("course_title", "Aal is well!!!");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("dashboard").setIndicator("Dashboard",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.dashboard))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

enter code here
```

This code is using tabhost i want to do the same using actionbar with fragmants for android 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onCreateView()` on Fragment and also `getActivity().` will give you direct access to `Activity`